# Where would a transformer be installed for a Tesup wind turbine?

Tags: electrical, solar-panels, inverter

2 months ago I ordered the New Tesup 5k Wind Turbine, and the Matching Charge Controller along with a Delta 5k Grid Tie inverter.

I received and installed it 8 weeks ago. I've previously worked as electrician.

I had help to put the Turbine up. I tested the Inverter with the 700watts of solar panels I already had & the inverter kicked in no problem producing free electric back to the grid. After testing was ok, I disconnected the Panels as they will not work alongside the turbine as well as the panels; too much power could overload the inverter. Anyway. I connected the Wind Turbine correctly as shown on Tesups Video online, although still not that helpful. 3 wires were connected to turbine then onto three inputs on the Charge Controller.  Don't matter which way around according to Tesup. Then I connected Solar Connectors using solar cable + to plus on inverter & - to - to inverter. So far so good.

The inverter has earth connected to casing and to ground rod. Then there are the 3 cables L N E on the inverters dedicated plug which is wired to an AC disconnect Switch then it runs from my shed to the CU in my property via armored cable. It was on 30mA RCD that kept tripping. It is also wired through recommended 25A fused switch.

I've since ordered then installed a 100mA RCD, but again keeps tripping as soon as the turbine starts up & inverter synchronizes. I've tried wiring in different ways that were safe, but I'm now at the end of my tether as I cannot get this bloody turbine to do it's job. There's no issue using the Solar panels. I'm reluctant to get a 300mA RCD, a as suggested by someone as I did a temp test by wiring direct to the mains using no fuses or RCD as Testup kept saying there should be no switches or inline fuses at all.

Nothing to trip this time but as usual the Inverter kept saying same old thing. it keeps coming up with Code F24, which I believe is Residual Current overload.

Tesup suggest using a transformer. If that is the case: What transformer? Where does it go? Before the inverter or after?

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. _Please_ edit this to include some formatting to make it easier to read. As it stands, it's a wall of nearly incomprehensible text and it's really hard to fathom what you're saying. Also, if you'll take the [tour], you'll see that this is a Question & Answer forum, not a general discussion board. The only question I see is "they even suggest using a transformer?", which should be answerable by reading the documentation and/or visiting the vendor's web site.

Comment: Could you [edit] in part numbers or model numbers for these items, please? And perhaps also add pictures of the connection area in question?

Comment: Neither do we with no voltages provided or the transformer if it is buck or boost. Removed electrician comment since it’s gone now, but still needs clarifications.we need voltages measured at input to inverter

Answer (score 2):

We Americans have a word: ["Get-there-itis"](https://www.aopa.org/training-and-safety/air-safety-institute/accident-analysis/featured-accidents/epilot-asf-accident-reports-get-there-itis).  The disease of focusing on one task to the negligence of safety.

**The RCD is there to protect your home from fire and its occupants from electric shock.** Downgrading it from 30mA to 100mA is not an appropriate method to troubleshoot a ground fault. Who cares whether the ground fault is 30-100ma, 100-300ma, 300-1000ma or whatever?  It needs to be fixed no matter the current. So I fail to see the point.

And then you have a second, independent instrument warning you of a ground fault.  So there's not really a doubt here.  This is a straightforward "find and fix", and you're an electrician. Allegedly.  Well, what are you waiting for?

To refresh on "ground faults", the normal flow of current is a loop.  Out the "live" and back the "neutral". On these two wires, flow is equal and opposite, and accounts for 100% of current flow.  There is no current flow on anything else.

Because the currents in live and neutral are equal and opposite, they "cancel each other out" magnetically.  That means, if you gather the insulated live and neutral wire together, and put a "clamp ammeter" around them *(not earth)*, the ammeter should read zero because the opposite currents are canceling out.

Also, since all current is on live and neutral, putting a clamp meter around earth only should read zero.

As a diagnostic measure, I would remove  the solar charge controller and wire in a plain receptacle on that same circuit, and then plug in a random yard tool.  See if that also trips the RCD.  If it does, that indicates a wiring problem between there and the consumer unit.

And the cable directly from windmill to the first module is *3-phase power* of variable voltage, so you have 3 "live" wires, no neutral and I don't know if you have an earth there.  So in that case clamp all 3 phases.

If this "3-phase" stuff is new to you, I can see where you might have mistaken it for "live neutral earth" - that would be your ground fault right there.

Another common source of ground faults is certain "earthing deniers" who believe neutral and earth are the same thing, and tie them together or combine them into one wire.  That's not going to work.

Having spent some time looking at TESUP's videos (insofar as one can spend all that much time looking at 1-minute videos), I can tell you they are entirely worthless.  The written manual is not great, but much better than the videos.  All of it seems like it was made by people who didn't understand the product - clearly the people who know anything are now working for Bayraktor lol.  I strongly advise against relying on "Videos" for your learning, as everyone who comes here and says that they used videos as their guide, has been terribly misled.  They just don't work.

Comment: Yes, I used to be an electrician but due to a head injury I would not pass as an electrian now as the brain injury has wiped a fair bit of my memmory. Meaning all the tests I used to remember to do I can no longer. & although I remember snipits. Anyway, I've since got another electrician in who has confirmed everything has been done correctly apart from one thing. I misread the voltage level incorrectly, so the armoured cable going from my shed to the mains in my bungalow was the wrong one. it's tripping because of this. the cable was 2.5mm should be 8mm. ordered 10mm instead.